# Garage Door Opener Carriage "Camming Out"

Tags: garage-door-opener, garage-door

When I attempt to open my garage door using the opener, the door stops moving and the opener emits a terrible sound (like an impact drill or a hammmering sound) that I assume is the opener's carriage riding on top of the screw without moving.

I've taken a short video of this happening to illustrate.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IyMVfMBquLs

This has gotten progressively worse over the past week or so.  When I first found out it would lift a couple of feet before stopping like this.  A gentle lift would assist it back into motion.

When the door is disconnected, it seems to lift as easily as it has before.  I don't feel it binding or see any of the pulleys or rollers sticking.  I've tried lubricating the rollers where they're held to the door to no benefit.  The springs have been replaced in the last couple years but not so recently that I'd associate the springs with the issue.

How do I fix this?

**Re: comments:**

- The opener is a [Genie H6000](https://www.geniecompany.com/product-support/model-h6000---legacy-screw-drive-series), specifically an H6000-07/M
- The screw and coupler appear to be turning freely without stuttering.  https://youtube.com/watch?v=iXXxmTjnJmM
- I can't tell if there's anything abnormal at the trolley or not, other than the trolley not moving.  [Here's video](https://youtube.com/watch?v=erB4N2cft_w)—the pitch alters when I apply a little pressure to see if the front of the trolley is engaging or not.  Either end of the trolley has grease/lubricant on it (which has not been recently added).

[image: garage opener trolley/carriage showing grease at the end]

- Trying to record this to share seems to have worsened the problem so that my trying to assist it open doesn't allow the trolley / carriage to engage.  I'm starting to think buying a new carriage is the next logical step, but this isn't my wheelhouse.

Comment: Thanks. The fact that grease is being sputtered out like that implies that the gear in the trolley is shot. JACK is right. Balance the door well and replace that part.

Comment: Balance the door... and grease the rollers and the track; there's a reason it broke.

Comment: @Mazura is [the description of balancing on this website](https://www.thespruce.com/balance-your-garage-door-to-become-level-1398027) correct?  The door was never slamming shut or rapidly opening and is a one-arm lift when disconnected from the lifting screw, but maybe a little heavy of a one-arm lift.  It's set up with extension springs so I can try the last hole up and see if that's a more appropriate amount of spring lift; the springs themselves are only a couple years old since I had one give out in 2020, so hopefully I don't need to go buy stronger ones.

Comment: Replacing that gear... ok. Basically anything else that isn't greasing something... even though I do all of this for a living; I call a guy. I ain't messing with no torsion springs.

Comment: @Mazura luckily I have extension springs, which don't seem to be nearly as dangerous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to remove the cover and check the movement of the drive shaft when the motor starts. It looks like it is slipping. That could be caused by a failing motor or the sprocket slipping on the drive shaft. It could just be a failed shear pin or roll pin but you'll need to do some more indepth checking.

Based on update to the question, it looks like the carriage assembly, shown below from Amazon,  has a stripped gear interface and needs replacement. You can get the part right from the link in your question.

[image]

Comment: You can see the drive shaft by simply looking at the rail. There's an open slot.

Comment: I had one where the plastic worm gear had worn out.   That would cause the symptoms described.

Comment: The carriage seems to have been it; same-day shipping to the rescue, and swapping the carriages is easier than I thought it'd be (two pins and a bolt, all of which were easy to get to).